# Multi-tenancy in Google IoT core

Tags: multi-tenant, google-cloud-iot

Is there a provision to use Google IoT core in multi-tenant way so that different user can use the same project but still only see their own device registries, devices etc?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way for you to solve your problem is to partition your users by project.

Particularly if the user is an organization|customer, this would provide you and the customer with the project's security boundary too. This would also give you partitioned registries and their devices.

A downside is in having to manage more projects but this is low effort.

Beyond perhaps the additional complexity, what would you not be able to achieve using multiple projects that you'd need?

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to DazWilkin's answer, if you DON'T partition your users by Project, then billing will all be put under one umbrella, which may not be something you want to do. You can't split billing within the same project to say "This registry get billed to this account, and that registry to that account". That may not be a requirement, but it's something to think about.